# Results from clicking on the logo are different

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, new-nav

When I click on the Stack Overflow logo I used to get results along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=recentlyactive:

- new questions
- recommended tags
- recently active

This same behavior still happens when I click on the meta.so logo, which redirects to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=recentlyactive.

Now when I click on the logo, I get https://stackoverflow.com/questions/need-answers?show=all&sort=recentlyactive&pageSize=50.

How can I get the old behavior back?

#### Note: clicking the tabs doesn't change the results back

[example video of what happens when clicking the tabs](https://youtu.be/Y4cZJN75Pz8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site *doesn't* remember your tab selection, instead there's a tiny home icon in the top right of the results list which changes what gets shown by default.

I must have clicked one of the options at some point without realizing it. Clicking on the "new" option from the list switched everything back to normal.

[image: expanded home dropdown]

Comment: I believe this is only on the new nav.

Comment: @NathanOliver, this question is tagged with [tag:new-nav]

Comment: Ah so it is.  It wasn't originally.

Comment: @NathanOliver, yes that was an oversight on my part, but it was corrected by the time I posted this answer.

Answer (score 2):

The site remembers your selections for which tab of the homepage (or the /questions page) you most recently selected, along with the page size you've selected.  So the links that you're seeing are what you see *because those are the options you've most recently selected*.  If you select different options, then that's what you'll see the next time you navigate to the homepage.

Comment: Except it's not changing back when I click the tabs.

Comment: Actually, you can choose what you see by default with the little house icon menu.  It was added a while ago, but I can't find the post about it.

Comment: @davidism, found it